# How to Query a 'Has many Through' Relation in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Rails 5 app with the following models:

`User.rb`,
`Campaign.rb`,
`UserCampaign.rb`

The relation is `User has many Campaigns through UserCampaign`. With this relation I can query `@user.campaigns` to find all campaigns related to that user. So far so good.

The UserCampaign schema looks like this:

```
create_table "user_campaigns", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "campaign_id"
  t.bigint "user_id"
  t.boolean "responded", default: false
  t.index ["campaign_id"], name: "index_user_campaigns_on_campaign_id"
  t.index ["user_id", "campaign_id"], name: "index_user_campaigns_on_user_id_and_campaign_id"
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_user_campaigns_on_user_id"
end
```

Ideally, I would like to write `@user.campaigns.where(responded: false)`. However, I get the following error:

`PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column campaigns.responded does not exist
LINE 1: ...izard_id" WHERE "user_campaigns"."user_id" = $1 AND "campaigns"....
                                                             ^
: SELECT "campaigns".* FROM "campaigns" INNER JOIN "user_campaigns" ON "campaigns"."id" = "user_campaigns"."campaign_id" WHERE "user_campaigns"."user_id" = $1 AND "campaigns"."responded" = $2`

I'm aware that I get this because `responded` is a column on UserCampaign and not Campaign. What is the best way to make a join to include the responded column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column campaigns.responded does not exist

You should rewrite your query like below

```
@user.campaigns.joins(:user_campaigns).where(user_campaigns: {responded: false})
```

Comment: Awesome, that works. After I have become more confident in Rails I'm starting to think about optimisation and performance. How 'expensive' is a join query like this compared to a normal non-join query? Is that even a question that can be answered? Cheers.

Comment: @Andy Read the concept of [*Eager Loading*](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations). You will understand :)